# Blade view not printing data from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've got a simple enough array of user information I'm trying to print.

I can send the information to the view fine. And a command like:

{{ $who->name }} will give me the name.

However when I do a foreach loop to print all the data in the array I get a bunch of numbers. 1 1 1 and blank spaces.

```
  @foreach ($who as $val)

          {{ $val }}

     @endforeach
```

What's going on?

Also, as the array has the titles of each value: ie "Name": "John Doe", is there a way to print the titles separately?

This is the controller:

```
 public function show(UserEdit $object) {
       return view('UserEdit', compact('object'));
   }
```

Note the controller is loading the model UserEdit, which has the user's data, and the id is generated from the route. Which I've confirmed works.

Edit: Updating files:

UserEdit.blade:

```
@extends('layout')


@section('content')
    <h1>User Profile Data {{ $object->First_Name }} {{ $object->Last_Name }}</h1>
        <br><br>

             @foreach ($object as $key=>$value)
                 {{ $key }}  {{ $value }}
             @endforeach


@stop
```

Gives error: Trying to get property of non-object

UserEntryController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\UserEdit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;

class UserEntryController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
       $columns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('users');
       $profile = UserEdit::all()->where('ID', '530');
       return view('UserEntry', compact('profile', 'columns'));
   }

   public function show(UserEdit $object) {
       //$columns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('users');
      // $profile = UserEdit::all()->where('ID', '530');
      // $who = UserEdit::find($ID);
       $object = $object->toArray();
       return view('UserEdit', compact('object'));
       //return $object;
   }

}
```

Routes:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('DB', 'DBController@index');
            //$tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
            //$titles = DB::select("SELECT * FROM topneeds(Name, Abbrev, jobtitle, region, detail)");

            //return view('DB', compact('titles'));
Route::get('Sort', 'SortController@index');
Route::get('User', 'UserEntryController@index');
route::get('User/{object}', 'UserEntryController@show');
```

UserEdit:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserEdit extends Model  {



    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['ID', <--67 values-->, 'remember_token'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [];

}
```

Comment: Did you try: `{{ $val->name }}` in the foreach. This should loop all names. You've got 1 1 1 because you didn't specified what you want `$val` to display

Comment: I did. It threw an error: Trying to get property of non-object, because this is an array from a model I think I'm new to Laravel so I don't know how they do a lot of things yet.
If I do {{ $who->name}} we get the name as expected.

Comment: Then try `{{ $val['name'] }}`

Comment: That prints blanks. Sometimes I love Murphy's Law

Comment: Is @Rubab answer work for you? If not show us what actually is in that array.

Comment: Since I'm still new to how laravel handles array's and objects, I'm unsure how to implement @rubab suggestion, though he is correct, that would be why it's not working.

Comment: I have added answer bellow. This is working form me. Hope it will work for you also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are sending object only to view. So lopping though that object giving you 1 1 1.

That's why this is working for you
{{ $obj->name }}

### Update

Convert your object to array

```
public function show(UserEdit $object) {
   $object = $object->toArray();
   return view('UserEdit', compact('object'));
}
```

Loop though that array

```
@foreach($object as $key=>$value)
   {{ $key }} - {{ $value }}
@endforeach
```

Edit from @Mugluck:
A quick note, for people who get "Undefined variable" when using the model type hint in this scenario. I solved it with this ($who is the route, which in this case is the ID):

```
   public function show($who) {
       $array = UserEdit::find($who)->toArray();
       return view('UserEdit', compact('array'));
   }
```

Apologies for mangled code. But this should give you the result.

Comment: So how would I change it to call data from the object, or convert the object into an array. I've been struggling to understand Laravel's process for these things. Should I change something in controller? Or change how the blade reads the object?

Comment: I'm incredibly thankful for the help Rubab and @s-i. But I'm still getting: Trying to get property of non-object (View: ...\resources\views\UserEdit.blade.php)
I've edited my main post to account for the changed code.

Comment: you are accessing as object after converting that object to array in the view. Remove <h1>User Profile Data {{ $object->First_Name }} {{ $object->Last_Name }}</h1>

Comment: or if you want to show first name and last name then do  $object['First_Name'] and $object['Last_Name'] which is the general way of accessing data from array using keys

Comment: Ooooh. So that's what that syntax means. Thank you. :) I will test.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your controller like this. This should pass an object to blade:

```
return view('UserEdit')->with(compact('object'));
```

Then you should be able to use it your blade like

```
@if ($object)
   @foreach($object as $val)
      {{ $val->name }}
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Update: Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21947573/4199784)

Comment: Those links are incredibly useful discussions.

Comment: You're welcome. I've mentioned how to access the name in my comment under the question. It isn't different than `$object['First/Last_Name']`. Glad you found the answer you've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you have array in $val. so you cant do this:-

```
@foreach ($who as $val)

      {{ print_r($val) }}

 @endforeach
```

Comment: I doubt that he want to print actual array. He want to use data from that array.

Comment: if he want to use data form that array, then he can use: {{ $val->name }}.

Comment: @mahipal-negi that will double up the unspecified values.